# ESP8266 SQLite always reset

Tags: c, sqlite

I do not know english. I'm using google translate. I apologize in advance.

I will use ESP8266 in a project that I will run on battery. For this reason, I do not want to use an SD card.
I will use the database in FLASH using SPIFFS.

The example I got from the ESP8266 sqlite3 library runs the sql commands in the SETUP paragraph. But when I call these commands from outside of SETUP with FUNCTION, the device is reset. Below I present both codes for your information.

I am already grateful for your help.
This is the original library sample. It always works.

```
/*
    This creates two empty databases, populates values, and retrieves them back
    from the SPIFFS file system.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <vfs.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <FS.h>
extern "C" {
#include "user_interface.h"
}
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

void WiFiOff() {
   wifi_station_disconnect();
   wifi_set_opmode(NULL_MODE);
   wifi_set_sleep_type(MODEM_SLEEP_T);
   wifi_fpm_open();
   wifi_fpm_do_sleep(0xFFFFFFF);
}

const char* data = "Callback function called";
static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
   int i;
   Serial.printf("%s: ", (const char*)data);
   for (i = 0; i<argc; i++){
       Serial.printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
   }
   Serial.printf("\n");
   return 0;
}

int db_open(const char *filename, sqlite3 **db) {
   int rc = sqlite3_open(filename, db);
   if (rc) {
       Serial.printf("Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(*db));
       return rc;
   } else {
       Serial.printf("Opened database successfully\n");
   }
   return rc;
}

char *zErrMsg = 0;
int db_exec(sqlite3 *db, const char *sql) {
   Serial.println(sql);
   long start = micros();
   int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
   if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
       Serial.printf("SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
       sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   } else {
       Serial.printf("Operation done successfully\n");
   }
   Serial.print(F("Time taken:"));
   Serial.println(micros()-start);
   return rc;
}

void setup() {

   Serial.begin(74880);
   sqlite3 *db1;
   sqlite3 *db2;
   int rc;

   system_update_cpu_freq(SYS_CPU_160MHZ);
   WiFiOff();

   if (!SPIFFS.begin()) {
       Serial.println("Failed to mount file system");
       return;
   }

   // list SPIFFS contents
   Dir dir = SPIFFS.openDir("/");
   while (dir.next()) {    
       String fileName = dir.fileName();
       size_t fileSize = dir.fileSize();
       Serial.printf("FS File: %s, size: %ld\n", fileName.c_str(), (long) fileSize);
   }
   Serial.printf("\n");

   // remove existing file
   SPIFFS.remove("/test1.db");
   SPIFFS.remove("/test2.db");

   sqlite3_initialize();

   // Open databases
   File db_file_obj_1;
   vfs_set_spiffs_file_obj(&db_file_obj_1);
   if (db_open("/FLASH/test1.db", &db1))
       return;
   File db_file_obj_2;
   vfs_set_spiffs_file_obj(&db_file_obj_2);
   if (db_open("/FLASH/test2.db", &db2))
       return;

   rc = db_exec(db1, "CREATE TABLE test1 (id INTEGER, content);");
   if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
       sqlite3_close(db1);
       sqlite3_close(db2);
       return;
   }
   rc = db_exec(db2, "CREATE TABLE test2 (id INTEGER, content);");
   if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
       sqlite3_close(db1);
       sqlite3_close(db2);
       return;
   }

   rc = db_exec(db1, "INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (1, 'Hello, World from test1');");
   if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
       sqlite3_close(db1);
       sqlite3_close(db2);
       return;
   }
   rc = db_exec(db2, "INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (1, 'Hello, World from test2');");
   if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
       sqlite3_close(db1);
       sqlite3_close(db2);
       return;
   }

   rc = db_exec(db1, "SELECT * FROM test1");
   if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
       sqlite3_close(db1);
       sqlite3_close(db2);
       return;
   }
   rc = db_exec(db2, "SELECT * FROM test2");
   if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
       sqlite3_close(db1);
       sqlite3_close(db2);
       return;
   }

   sqlite3_close(db1);
   sqlite3_close(db2);

}

void loop() {
}
```

This is the version of the function called from outside of SETUP.

The device resets when other functions are called except OPENDATABASE (such as Select Values ​​()).

```
/*
    This creates two empty databases, populates values, and retrieves them back
    from the SPIFFS file system.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <vfs.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <FS.h>
extern "C" {
#include "user_interface.h"
}
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

sqlite3* db1;

void WiFiOff() {
    wifi_station_disconnect();
    wifi_set_opmode(NULL_MODE);
    wifi_set_sleep_type(MODEM_SLEEP_T);
    wifi_fpm_open();
    wifi_fpm_do_sleep(0xFFFFFFF);
}

const char* data = "Callback function called";
static int callback(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName) {
    int i;
    Serial.printf("%s: ", (const char*)data);
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        Serial.printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
    }
    Serial.printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int db_open(const char* filename, sqlite3** db) {
    int rc = sqlite3_open(filename, db);
    if (rc) {
        Serial.printf("Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(*db));
        return rc;
    }
    else {
        Serial.printf("Opened database successfully\n");
    }
    return rc;
}

char* zErrMsg = 0;
int db_exec(sqlite3* db, const char* sql) {
    Serial.println(sql);
    long start = micros();
    int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        Serial.printf("SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    }
    else {
        Serial.printf("Operation done successfully\n");
    }
    Serial.print(F("Time taken:"));
    Serial.println(micros() - start);
    return rc;
}


void OpenDatabase();
void CreateTable();
void InsertValues();
void SelectValues();

void setup() {

    Serial.begin(74880);    

    system_update_cpu_freq(SYS_CPU_160MHZ);
    WiFiOff();

    if (!SPIFFS.begin()) {
        Serial.println("Failed to mount file system");
        return;
    }

    // list SPIFFS contents
    Dir dir = SPIFFS.openDir("/");
    while (dir.next()) {
        String fileName = dir.fileName();
        size_t fileSize = dir.fileSize();
        Serial.printf("FS File: %s, size: %ld\n", fileName.c_str(), (long)fileSize);
    }
    Serial.printf("\n");

    // remove existing file
    SPIFFS.remove("/test1.db");    

    sqlite3_initialize();

    OpenDatabase();
    CreateTable();
    InsertValues();
    SelectValues();    */

    // list SPIFFS contents
    dir = SPIFFS.openDir("/");
    while (dir.next()) {
        String fileName = dir.fileName();
        size_t fileSize = dir.fileSize();
        Serial.printf("FS File: %s, size: %ld\n", fileName.c_str(), (long)fileSize);
    }
    Serial.printf("\n");
    
}

void loop() {
}

void OpenDatabase() {    
    int rc;
    // Open databases
    File db_file_obj_1;
    vfs_set_spiffs_file_obj(&db_file_obj_1);
    if (db_open("/test1.db", &db1)) return;    
}

void CreateTable() {    
    int rc;
    // Create Table
    rc = db_exec(db1, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test1 (id INTEGER, content);");
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db1);        
        return;    
    }    
}

void InsertValues() {    
    int rc;
    // Insert Values
    rc = db_exec(db1, "INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (1, 'Hello, Hurol from test1');");
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db1);        
        return;    
    }    
}

void SelectValues() {    
    int rc;
    // Select Values
    rc = db_exec(db1, "SELECT * FROM test1");
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db1);
        return;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `File db_file_obj_1; vfs_set_spiffs_file_obj(&db_file_obj_1);` Not knowing about the library, setting a pointer to non-static local object (for later use?) looks weird and dangerous.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.

File db_file_obj_1; vfs_set_spiffs_file_obj (& db_file_obj_1);

If I remove these commands it gives EXCEPTION (29) error.

Comment: worked sir. File db_file_obj_1; vfs_set_spiffs_file_obj(&db_file_obj_1); 

I left this command in the setup section. So once it worked. 

In this block, SPIFFS is set again each time.

Final:

... SETUP >
sqlite3_initialize();

    File db_file_obj_1;
    vfs_set_spiffs_file_obj(&db_file_obj_1);

    OpenDatabase();
    CreateTable();
    InsertValues();
    SelectValues();    

   ...
}
void OpenDatabase() {    
    int rc;
    // Open databases    
    if (db_open("/test1.db", &db1)) return;    
}

Life is beautiful when shared.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Then come back and add an answer of your own if your issue is solved. Later you are allowed to mark it, so that others quickly find it. Another hint: When you have new information, don't post a comment, it will commonly not be read. Instead [edit] your question. Have a lot of fun!

Answer (score 0):

worked!
File db_file_obj_1; vfs_set_spiffs_file_obj(&db_file_obj_1); I left this command in the setup section. So once it worked.
In this block, SPIFFS is set again each time.

Final: ... SETUP >

```
sqlite3_initialize(); 

File db_file_obj_1; 
vfs_set_spiffs_file_obj(&db_file_obj_1); 

OpenDatabase(); 
CreateTable(); 
InsertValues(); 
SelectValues(); 
... } 

void OpenDatabase() { 
int rc; 
// Open databases 
if (db_open("/test1.db", &db1)) return; 
}
```

Life is beautiful when shared.